# negative lookahead regular expression python

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have a list of strings, I want to match a keyword if is not preceded by an "and". However, I would like to include the keyword if the "and" is preceded by another word. Taking into account that the position of the "and" is not the same in all the strings.

In my example below I would like to match strings that have the word "book", only if the word "book" is not after "and" unless the "and" is precede by a "tall" (the first and the third item in my list). My attempt was using

```
^((?!((?<!tall)\band\b)).)*book
```

but it is not working. I'm not sure if I can include a negative look behind inside a negative lookahead

1. is a tall and wide book
2. is a computer and a book of instructions
3. book with a pretty cover

4.computer with nice headphones

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this using an alternation with both a positive and negative lookbehind:

```
((?<!\band )|(?<=\btall and ))book
```

### Demo

The logic here is to match the word `book` if either of the following two conditions are true:

- `book` is not preceded by the word `and` at all
- `book` is preceded by `and`, which in turn is also preceded by `tall`

I didn't bother to include any Python code, but from what I gleaned in your question, the meat and potatoes is figuring out the regex, rather than the Python code.

Comment: Thank you, the only inconvenient that I have is that I don't know the exact position of the "and", if it was right before "book", I think it your answer would work. However, in my real list the position of the "and" variate a lot

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question, or else the regex logic you gave is not accurate for your actual problem.

Comment: Thank you, you are entirely right, I just rephrase it

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that my approach was not entirely wrong. It works when I take out the first boundary.

```
^((?!((?<!tall) and\b)).)*book
```

I don't know yet why it doesn't work when I include that boundary. But it works. Thank you